# Generate random time in hour and minute format python

Tags: python

I want to generate a timestamp only in hour and minutes format, like this:

```
154h 27m
```

Please check my logic below

```
planned_downtime = timedelta(hours=random.randrange(150))
```

However, the result is coming in seconds. To convert it to above mentioned format, I applied this:

```
planned_downtime.strftime("%H %M")
```

But I'm getting errors. How can I convert this randomly generated time in above format?

Comment: Question got closed but use this
`print(f"{planned_downtime.seconds // 3600}h {planned_downtime.seconds // 60 % 60}m")`

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe:

```
m = random.randint(0,60)
h = random.randint(0,24)
ts = f'{h}h {m}m'

print(ts)
15h 48m
```

Comment: This will generate the time as string, later I want to calculate their differences as well.